# substring and pattern matching to extract data from string in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I work with postgres 11.

I have text and I want to extract substring from theses text :

`"|a john dumas .|d 1941|e united states|=^A22306"`  the correct output should be  **john dumas .1941**

`"|a john dumas .|e united states|=^A22306"`  the correct output should be  **john dumas .**

`"|a john dumas .|=^A22306 |e united states |d 1941 |f admin "` the correct output should be  **john dumas .1941**

`"|a john dumas .|f admin |d 1941  |=^A22306 |e united states"` the correct output should be  **john dumas .1941**

`"|a john dumas .|f admin |d 1941 "` the correct output should be  **john dumas .1941**

`"|a john dumas . "`    the correct output should be  **john dumas .**

`"john dumas .|e united states |d 1941 "` the correct output should be  **john dumas .1941**

`"john dumas ."`   the correct output should be  **john dumas .**

if the text contain `|a` so read from `|a` until find first character`|`
and if the text contain `|d` so read from `|d` until find first character `|` after `|d` like example 1 and 3 and 4

if the text contain `|a` so read from `|a` until find first character `|`
and if the text contain `|d` and not contain any character `|` after `|d`
so read from `|d` until end of the text  like example 5

if the text contain `|a` and if the text not contain any character `|` after `|a`
so read from `|a` until end of the text  like example 6

if the text contain `|a` and not contain any character `|d` so read from `|a` until find first character `|` after `|a` like example 2

if the text not contain `|a`  read from the beginning the text until find first character `|`
and if the text contain `|d` and not contain any character `|` after `|d`
so read from `|d` until end of the text  like example 7

if the text not contain `|a` and not contain any character `|`  so read from all text from beginning like example 8

the main goal of all example is to read from `|a`  and from `|d`
and if the text not contain `|a` so read from beginning of the text.

**I want to have one query select which can process all these examples.**

I try with this code but the problem is that this code give the correct output only for the first example

```
select  replace(substring('|a john dumas .|d 1941|e united states|=^A22306' from '\|a(.+)\|e'), '|d', '')
```

the output is correct `" john dumas . 1941"`

can someone help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this query

```
WITH data AS 
         (SELECT '|a john dumas .|d 1941|e united states|=^A22306' AS input
UNION ALL SELECT '|a john dumas .|e united states|=^A22306' AS input
UNION ALL SELECT '|a john dumas .|=^A22306 |e united states |d 1941 |f admin ' AS input
UNION ALL SELECT '|a john dumas .|f admin |d 1941  |=^A22306 |e united states' AS input
UNION ALL SELECT '|a john dumas .|f admin |d 1941 ' AS input
UNION ALL SELECT '|a john dumas . ' AS input
UNION ALL SELECT '|a john dumas .|d ت. 1941-|e محرر.|=^A22306' AS input
UNION ALL SELECT 'john dumas .|d 1941|e united states ' AS input  
UNION ALL SELECT 'john dumas .' AS input)

SELECT CONCAT(
       SUBSTRING(input, '^(?:\|a\s*)?([^|]+)'),
       SUBSTRING(input, '(?:\|d\s*)([^|]+)')) AS output
FROM data
```

See demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Mp5JUL5v)

Comment: thank you a lot.
but I have only one exception if the text like this : |a john dumas .|d ت. 1941-|e محرر.|=^A22306
using your code the output is "john dumas ."  and not john dumas . ت. 1941-  which is correct using the same concept

Comment: Does it mean that you want to match all text after `|d` and not just the numbers?

Comment: Yes I want to display all text after |d